# Is it possible to dynamically create a function with a receiver (method) in go?

Tags: reflection, methods, go, runtime

I was reading about [reflect.MakeFunc](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeFunc) and was wondering if there's also a way to create a [Method](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Method) (a function with a receiver) at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the receiver's type [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) would change on runtime if you did this. As you may know, Go in its current implementations is type checked at compile time. You would require runtime interface-implementation checks on every function-call that takes an interface argument if a type could  suddenly acquire (or lose) methods at runtime.

> a way to create a Method (a function with a receiver) at runtime

Technically, though, you *could* build a value representing a method attached to an arbitrary type by forking the reflect package. This would not, however, change said type's method set because it'd be essentially a hack around Go's type system.

---

> What about swapping method pointers on an object?

Go, unlike e.g. Java does not embed a virtual method dispatch table in concrete values, [only in interface values](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces). If you're willing to get your hands dirty you could get a hold of a [`reflect.nonEmptyInterface`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/reflect/value.go#L174) and modify its *itable* (itab field).

Comment: Interesting... What about swapping method pointers on an object? (maybe I should ask that in another thread) - and yes, I'm well aware I'm not "supposed" to be doing any of this ;)