# Go Reflection - Dynamic Type with Methods

Tags: go, methods, interface, reflect

Using Go's `reflect` package, you can create dynamic struct types using [reflect.StructOf()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf):

```
typ := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
        {
            Name: "Height",
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(float64(0)),
            Tag:  `json:"height"`,
        },
        {
            Name: "Age",
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(int(0)),
            Tag:  `json:"age"`,
        },
    })
```

Is there any way to create functions/methods that take this new dynamic type as a receiver? Specifically, I'd like to create a dynamic type using `StructOf()` that implements an interface (which has several methods defined) such that `reflect.New(typ).Interface().(InterfaceType)` will succeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to dynamically create a function with a receiver (method) in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481354/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-a-function-with-a-receiver-method-in-go)

Comment: No would be the answer.